# Focus not working for input fields Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I am trying to add input fields dynamically using jquery.I am able to add the input fields but not able to move the focus to next input field.

Code is as follows:-

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

  $(scntDiv).keypress( function(event) {
    if (event.which==13){
      $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
      i++;
      return false;
    }

  });

  $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
    if( i > 2 ) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
  <p>
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: press Enter key it will automatically add...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***1.*** `id` need to be unique per element, so change `id='p_scnt'` to `class='p_scnt'` for your input boxes.As well as use `class="remScnt"` instead of `id="remScnt"` for remove buttons too

***2.*** Use `$('.p_scnt:last').focus();` to add focus on dynamically created input-box

***3*** As you mentioned in a comment that you used jQuery latest version and hence `.live()` is not working, now you need to use [jQuery event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

***Working snippet:-***

```js
$(function() {
  var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
  var i = $('#p_scents p').length;

  $(scntDiv).keypress( function(event) {
    if (event.which==13){
    alert($(event.target).val());
      $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
      $('.p_scnt:last').focus();
      i++;
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click','.remScnt',function() { 
    if( i > 1 ) {
      $(this).parents('p').remove();
      i--;
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* { 
  font-family:Arial; 
}
h2 { 
  padding:0 0 5px 5px; 
}
h2 a { 
  color: #224f99; 
}
a { 
  color:#999; 
  text-decoration: none; 
}
a:hover { 
  color:#802727; 
}
p { 
  padding:0 0 5px 0; 
}

input { 
  padding:5px; 
  border:1px solid #999; 
  border-radius:4px; 
  -moz-border-radius:4px; 
  -web-kit-border-radius:4px; 
  -khtml-border-radius:4px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

***Note:-*** to `alert()` values do `alert($(event.target).val());` inside `if (event.which==13){` condition.

Comment: i want to alert the value after entering and clicking the enter  button.

Comment: @Ravi check my edited solution code as well as note section. I have added `alert()` code.

Comment: Thanks @Alive to Die

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
        
        $(scntDiv).keypress( function(event) {
        if (event.which==13){
                $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i +'" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
                 $("#p_scnt_" + i).focus();
                i++;
                return false;
                }
              
        });
        
        $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
                if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).parents('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
                return false;
        });
});
```

```css
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
```

You can give the unique ID to each new raw appended and after append you can trigger a focus using that ID.

Comment: don't even need the id, can just target it from the appended element: ...appendTo(scntDiv).find('input:first').focus()

Comment: yes but as I saw OP is using same ID multiple times, I have improved that also. Thanks for your suggestion. @hairmot

Comment: instead of using multiple `id's` i will recommend using  `class` for this. You can check my answer for reference

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @AlivetoDie can you please tell me what difference it will make if we use ID or class? Thanks :)

Comment: @hairmot  instead of using multiple `id's` i will recommend using  `class` for this. You can check my answer for reference. Also  in your comment `('input:first')` need to be `('input:last')`

Comment: @SmitRaval  class is especially maid to point a group of elements. While `id` maid to point specific element. It's up-to-you that you will create unique `id` per element or go with `class` to address the group in a single-time easily.Anyhow creating multiple `id's` for the same kind of element structure is not recommended at all.

Comment: @AlivetoDie the find is scoped to the parent paragraph tag so it doesn't really matter which you use as there is only one input per paragraph in the given example. It seems redundant to add classes when the selector i previously mentioned works just fine.